# How do I disable TDateTimePicker dates beyond a certain time?

Tags: delphi, datetimepicker

How do I disable TDateTimePicker from allowing selecting dates beyond the system date & time? E.g., if my system date is 06 Nov 2012, I should not be able to select dates beyond 06 Nov 2012.

Furthermore, can we do something for selecting dates only within a particular range?

Comment: Surely there is a misprint in your question.

Comment: Surely, @Andreas. Fixed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the `MaxDate` property of the `TDateTimePicker` class to set the maximum allowed date.

Somewhere in the form you can add

```
DateTimePicker1.MaxDate := Now;
```

Also, there is the `MinDate` property which prevents selection of dates older than the one specified.